# Difference between .html and .twig files

Tags: php, html, web, twig

Looking at the two files, they look very similar. Even at the top of a .twig file it says:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang = "en">
```

etc.

So clearly it is basically html. In the .php file it renders a .twig file and there are no .html files in the entire website's directory? I didn't know you could build websites with no html whatsoever?

Comment: Twig is a templating engine that outputs html. The browser only renders html. But since html can be a pain to write and very repetative, there are templating engines that make life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Html** is the final markup output that your browser will consume...

**Twig** is a templating engine for PHP that at the end will render as HTML markup with your dynamic data so your browser can consume it...